# Regex to find excel-like cell address in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am programming a spreadsheet-like software in Java. The cell may contain numbers, strings or equations. Equations contains cell references.

I need a java regular expression to single out the cell references. A cell reference would be a single Uppercase letter followed by a number.

I came up with:

```
 String pattern=".[A-Z]{1}\\d";
```

But this work only when the number is less than 10. Can you help me find a suitable regex?

Comment: The {1} part is just redundant. By default, a class of characters matches only one char.

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Z]{1}\d+
```

This will allow 1 or more numbers

Comment: @smit as part of the string syntax, probably yes

Comment: @user1925980 You could use this link for more information on regex. [Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I want to change the formulas when copied too. As in if content of cell A1 is "=A2+A3", when A1 is copied to cell B1 the cell contents of B1 should be "=B2+B3". Any idea how to modify the String?

Comment: @smit: I actually learnt regex from dat :) . but Thanks for the help.